# How to classify temporal disease data

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have some data for spread of H1N1. The three major categories of people are Uninfected, Infected & Carriers. This is a temporal data as in the tests were conducted monthly ($\rm Month_0$, $\rm Month_1$)

The dynamics of the flow are like this: Uninfected I have some data for spread of H1N1. The three major categories of people are Uninfected, Infected and Carriers. This is temporal data as the tests were conducted monthly ($\rm Month_0, Month_1$)

Here are the possibilities:

1. Uninfected $\leftrightarrow$ Carrier (Bidirectional)
2. Infected $\leftrightarrow$ Carrier (Bidirectional)
3. Uninfected $\rightarrow$ Carrier (Unidirectional)

$\rm Uninfected + Carrier + Infected = 9500$ (i.e., the same individuals were tested for $\rm Month_0$ and $\rm Month_1$). Each patient record is a $244$ row by $10$ column matrix, i.e., values of $244$ parameters. I have the data for $\rm Month_0$ for all these states and then for $\rm Month_1$.

I have to develop a predictive model which could classify a new patient into these categories. Which algorithm / models will work on this problem?

PS: The data size equals to $9500$, each (for 2 months). Each record $= 244\times 10$

[image: Data flow]

Comment: I think you should start with decision trees, since they are relatively easy to implement (see e.g. `rpart` package in `R`). And extensions such as random forests. Another option: since you clearly have different states, maybe something with Markov Chains can be useful? For this approach you have to make a model for the transition probabilities for going to the next month.

Comment: @Marcel10 Thanks, could you please suggest a tutorial which aligns  with my case study. Thing is Ive just started with ML & really dont know the terms,terminologies etc hence any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: with ML I assume you mean Maximum Likelihood? Do you have to use maximum likelihood (aka is it HW)? Anyway, googling 'decision tree tutorial r', gives enough useful hits. This [R-blogger](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-brief-tour-of-the-trees-and-forests/) gives examples for different decision tree packages. If you have no experience in Markov Chains, I don't think this will be the right approach (a lot of math needed to fully understand everything).

Comment: @Marcel10 By ML I meant Machine Learning. Im open to using any algo, but dont know which one would suit better for this case. Thanks

Comment: I would start with decision trees if I were you. They are relatively simple and you will learn a lot from it (especially what profiles of people are similar with respect to the probabilities to be in a specific state). Then you can always try other approaches (maybe SVM?).

Comment: @vinita learning mathjax also known as LaTex will be helpful in formulating your question (any questions actually) ...

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage you to start with simple classification techniques. Typically a logistic regression. Very simple, runs fast, many examples in R online. 
A simple decision tree is also an option (don't go for random forests if you don't have to).

Start with these, as they are simple to understand and have good implementations in R.

That will give you the capacity to classify a new patient. If you then want to predict changes of states and thinks like that, then it gets more complicated and other techniques are required - but only with properly formulated questions.

Answer (score 1):

Python scikit-learn allows for analysis like the one you are looking for: [scikit-learn RBF SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html)

Comment: This answer is too short. You should expand it.

Comment: @user143633 I second Joe_74 , your answer is way too short and it doesn't give any hints of a solution or any decent explanation.